# Check the change in the parameters of stable baselines custom policy

Tags: conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am trying to train a reinforcement learning model for collision avoidance using stable baselines. I am using a custom policy network. I have trained several models and they have converged to a stable reward, but it seems that the policy is input (observation space) independent meaning it takes fixed action irrespective of what observations it gets. I need to debug this issue, I guess checking the change in the parameters of the policy network might help. Does anyone know how I can debug the issue or how can I check the change in the parameters of the custom policy?